# BCP with non-printable Field terminators

Tags: sql-server-2008, bcp

Trying to import the [EPF files](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-enterprise-partner-feed.html) from Apple using BCP.  Apple use characters `\1` and `\2` as field and row terminators.  Unforunately these don't appears to be supported as BCP / BULK INSERT [field terminators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa196735%28v=sql.80%29.aspx), from the documentation:

> Note  Only the t, n, r, \, and 0 characters work with the backslash
>   escape character to produce a control character.

Is there alternative to BCP & BULK INSERT I could use to import the files in?  (apart from writing a utility to process the files myself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `BULK INSERT` You could work around this limitation with a dynamic query. In this example the `fieldterminator` is `CHAR(15)`:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000) = 
'bulk insert MyTable
from ''C:\spaced.txt''
with (
    firstrow=2
    , rowterminator=''\n''
    , fieldterminator='''+CHAR(15)+'''
)'
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL;
```